# How to make an array of Div IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make an array of all of the IDs of my divs will a class of .guycontainer

here is what I've tried:

```
    $(".guycontainer").each(function(index){
        arrayOfGuys= [];
        var c=$(this);
        arrayOfGuys.push(c.attr('id'));
        console.log(arrayOfGuys);       
    });
```

but in the console, it logs each ID as a separate array, not one array of all the IDS

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: that's because on each iteration you're overwriting arrayOfGuys with a new empty array... `x = 1; alert(x); // Why does x == 1?!?!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its getting overwritten on each iteration, move your array variable outside .each(), do:

```
var arrayOfGuys= [];
$(".guycontainer").each(function(index){
    var c=$(this);
    arrayOfGuys.push(c.attr('id'));
    console.log(arrayOfGuys);       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the creation of the array outside the loop, it won't be recreated for each iteration:

```
arrayOfGuys = [];
$(".guycontainer").each(function(){
  arrayOfGuys.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You can also use the `map` method:

```
arrayOfGuys = $(".guycontainer").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're re-initializing the array each time through the loop. You need to do that outside the loop:

```
var arrayOfGuys= [];
$(".guycontainer").each(function(index){
    var c=$(this);
    arrayOfGuys.push(c.attr('id'));    
}); 
console.log(arrayOfGuys);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfGuys= [];
$(".guycontainer").each(function(index){
        var c=$(this);
        arrayOfGuys.push(c.attr('id'));
        console.log(arrayOfGuys);       
});
```

The "function" in the "each" is a new function call... so that means when you were saying "arrayOfGuys=[]" you were actually creating a new array within that function call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery map method to iterate through the array of elements and return their ids like this:

```
var arrayOFGuys = $.map($(".guycontainer"), function(el){return $(el).attr("id")});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/q4MVd/

**Edit:** 

According to jquery

> If you wish to process a jQuery object — for example, $('div').map( callback ); — use .map() instead.

Comment: Using a jQuery object in the `$.map` method is an undocumented use, the documentation says that you should use the `.map` method instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/